# Different ways to get unique get_level_values()

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following `DataFrame df`:

```
df=
kind        A              B
names          a1      a2      b1      b2      b3
Time
0.0        0.7804  0.5294  0.1895  0.9195  0.0508
0.1        0.1703  0.7095  0.8704  0.8566  0.5513
0.2        0.8147  0.9055  0.0506  0.4212  0.2464
0.3        0.3985  0.4515  0.7118  0.6146  0.2682
0.4        0.2505  0.2752  0.4097  0.3347  0.1296
```

When I issue the command `levs = df.columns.get_level_values("kind")`, I get that `levs` is equal to

```
Index(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], dtype='object', name='kind')
```

whereas I would like to have that `levs` is equal to `Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object', name='kind')`.

One way to achieve such an objective could be to run `levs=list(set(levs))`, but I am wondering if there are any other simple methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `levels`:

```
out = df.columns.levels[0]
print (out)
Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')
```

EDIT: One idea with lookup by names of MultiIndex:

```
d = {v: k  for k, v in enumerate(df.columns.names)}
print (d)
{'kind': 0, 'names': 1}

out = df.columns.levels[d['kind']]
print (out)
Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object', name='kind')
```

Comment: Ah that is nice, but it would be nicer if I can call the levels by its name "kind" rather than its corresponding integer level :)

Comment: @Barzi2001 - One idea is use dict lookup, added to answer.

Comment: This is nice, in general, not only for this specific use-case. :)